# How to access a .net 6 Scoped object from logger Singleton

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I have a .NET 6 application with a Scoped service that holds data from the context running, like trace id, correlation id, etc., I want to use this data to enrich my log that is a structured json using Serilog lib overriding the `ILoggerFactory`.

I have a custom log Provider used in the Serilog `LoggerConfiguration` to format the text to json and inject data from this Scoped service, the problem is that logger is a singleton and I can not access this scoped object inside it.

I can not use IHttpContextAccessor because usually the code running on it is a BackgroundService to read some Queue's not an HTTP Request, and I can not use the ServiceProvider to create a scope, because I would lose the real current scope.

```cs
internal class CustomFormatter : ITextFormatter
    {
        private readonly ILogProvider _provider;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        static readonly JsonSerializerSettings _jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        public CustomFormatter(ILogProvider provider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
        {
            var logObj = _provider.Create(logEvent);

            // Error in this line, since ICustomContext is a scoped object
            var customContext = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICustomContext>();

            logObj.CorrelationId = customContext.correlationId;

            output.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logObj, _jsonOptions));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should provide details about your application configuration, there should be something about `ILoggerFactory` and call to `AddProvider` which will eventually sort out how to correctly reference `IHttpContextAccessor`

Comment: documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 exact approach for .net6 is perhaps a bit different than what I outlined above

Comment: If ComponentB cannot "live" longer than ComponentA, then ComponentA cannot reference it. An alternative is to create a DecoratedComponent which references both ComponentA and ComponentB, does whatever you need, and only has the lifetime of ComponentB

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Log enrichment (see https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment) to push the properties you are interested in onto the LogEvent.

You mention a HTTP request so I assume you can use the request middleware to achieve this.

Your scoped service registration,

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
```

The middleware registration,

```
public static void Configure(this WebApplication app)
{            
    ...

    app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();    
}
```

Your middlware class

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IMyService service)
    {
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", service.CorrelationId))
        {
            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

In your CustomFormatter,

```
if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("CorrelationId", out LogEventPropertyValue logEventPropertyValue))
{
    // Use the CorrelationId here in logEventPropertyValue
}
```